# Block empty user-agents nginx?

Tags: blocking, nginx

My site was under attack and I noticed all the user agents are blank. How can I block this with my nginx?

[image: Screenshot of Log File]

I have no idea what to block, if this is an empty user agent or what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391929/how-to-block-empty-user-agents-in-nginx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to block blank user agents by sending them a "403" or access denied message then this should work:

`if ($http_user_agent = "") { return 403; }`

Modifying this to do other things should be straightforward.